# How to put pager between multiple views?

Tags: 7, views, paging

I am finding the way to combine more than one views through pager, I would like to connect them using the pager. And I would like to provide the pager like what is on drupal site(documentation part) as shown in following image. So they show previous and next node. I am searching but did not find the way to combine multiple views. The views default pager is for its own content and can not apply to the direct to other views. Thanks
[image: Drupal.org Pager]

Comment: Depending on your use case, you could hard code them to your view as a footer `<a href="http://...">Next View</a>`

Comment: @NoSssweat, Yes that is also the way to do. If not by any module, will use this way to hard code, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you might have to rethink your content architecture. The type of pager your are looking for ideally applies to *content* and not *views*.
drupal.org uses the book navigation that comes from the `book` module in Drupal 7 core.

If you do not want to use the book module, you could also go with the [Nodequeue](https://drupal.org/project/nodequeue) module, which provides a similar pager (except the middle link `Up`).

If you still really need to add such pager to connect the views, you can do it by adding the markup to the view footer to link to other views (and theme it as per the design). Or to make it dynamic, implement `hook_views_pre_view` (or any similar hook) and change the link from from the footer. **Note:** This however, is very hard to maintain and not recommended.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answers. I am trying to do it with Nodequeue, but I am not getting how to create pager. I searched and found few article on Nodequeue but it does not have things for pager. If there is any tutorial could you please provide the link. Thanks

Comment: I end up using Book module for making the pager. thx